# Linker not finding libsystemd

Tags: 18.04, compiling, symbolic-link, ld

I'm trying to write a `systemd` service that uses the watchdog, and after

```
sudo apt install libsystemd-dev
```

I checked to make sure it was available:

```
$ ldconfig -p |grep systemd
    libsystemd.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0
    libsystemd.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so
    libnss_systemd.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_systemd.so.2
```

Then checked to make sure the linker could find it:

```
$ echo "int main(){}" | gcc -x c++ -Wl,--no-as-needed -llibsystemd - && ldd a.out | grep libsystemd
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibsystemd
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why can't `ld` find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-llibsystemd` doesn't look for `libsystemd` - it looks for `liblibsystemd`

As noted in `man g++`:

> ```
>   -l library
>        The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library,
>        which is actually a file named liblibrary.a.  The linker then uses
>        this file as if it had been specified precisely by name.
> ```

So, you want `-lsystemd`

```
echo "int main(){}" | gcc -x c++ -Wl,--no-as-needed -lsystemd - && ldd a.out | grep libsystemd
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! This was a pretty stupid mistake to have made on my side...

Comment: That's OK - we've all been there ;)